# Is it possible to make typesafe node-style callbacks?

Tags: typescript

Node callbacks look something like:

```
interface NodeCallback<TResult,TError> {
  (err: TError): void;
  (err: null, res: TResult): void;
}
```

So the callback will either get `err` or `res` but not both. Most of the typings I see have the types of `err` and `res` hard coded to their non-optional versions.

```
function readdir(path: string, callback?: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, files: string[]) => void): void;
```

This isn't strictly typesafe. For example this compiles fine:

```
fs.readdir('/', (err, files) => {
  if (err !== null) { // There's an error!
    files.forEach(log); // Still using the result just fine.
  }
})
```

You can make this more (well, kind of) safe by changing the signature to include all possible values.

```
function readdir(path: string, callback?: (err: null | NodeJS.ErrnoException, files?: string[]) => void): void;
```

But there's no way to specify the dependency between the two so you need to type assert `res` to quiet down `strictNullChecks`.

```
fs.readdir('/', (err, files) => {
  if (err === null) { // There's no error
    // files.forEach(log); // Won't compile
    (files as string[]).forEach(log); // Type assertion
    files!.forEach(log); // Nice shorthand
    if (files !== undefined) { // Type guard
      files.forEach(log);
    }
  }
})
```

This is not too bad except for:

- When you need to do it repeatedly.
- When you're not accessing a property so you *have* to type assert, which might mean you need to import another type. Really annoying. Type guards will avoid this but then you've got an unnecessary runtime penalty.
- It's still not actually safe. It's more in-your-face so you're forced to think about it, but we're mostly relying on manually asserting.

If you really wanted to you could do this with a `Result`-like discriminated union:

```
type Result<R,E>
  = { error: false, value: R }
  | { error: true, value: E }

function myFunction(callback: (res: Result<string, Error>) => void) {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    callback({ error: true, value: new Error('error!') });
  } else {
    callback({ error: false, value: 'ok!' })
  }
}

myFunction((res) => {
  if (res.error) {
    // type of res.value is narrowed to Error
  } else {
    // type of res.value is narrowed to string
  }
})
```

Which ends up being pretty nice honestly, but that's a lot of boilerplate and totally goes against common node style.

So my question is does typescript currently have a way to make this super common pattern both typesafe and convenient? I'm pretty sure the answer is no right now, and that's not a big deal, but I was just curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only good pattern I've seen, other than what you've done, looks like this:

```
function isOK<T>(err: Error | null, value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return !err;
}

declare function readdir(path: string, callback: (err: null | Error, files: string[] | undefined) => void): void;

readdir('foo', (err, files) => {
    if (isOK(err, files)) {
        files.slice(0);
    } else {
        // need to err! here but 'files' is 'undefined'
        console.log(err!.message);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is now possible with the TypeScript 4.6 feature [Control Flow Analysis for Dependent Parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#control-flow-analysis-for-dependent-parameters).

Here's the appropriate type for `readdir`:

```js
type readdir =
  ( path: string
  , cb: (...args: [NodeJS.ErrnoException, undefined] | [null, string[]]) => void
  ) => void
const myreaddir: readdir = fs.readdir as any
```

This catches the problem you were pointing out earlier:

```js
myreaddir('/', (err, files) => {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log(files.length)
             // └──── 18048: 'files' is possibly 'undefined'.
  }
})
```